# SQL select rows only once

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `pro` like this :

```
id    category   details
1         f        weqweq
2         m        dqweq
3         f        xcxzc
4         m        eqweqw
5         f        asweq
6         c        xzsda
```

Now if i try something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM pro
```

i get only `m` and `c`

if i try :

```
  SELECT category FROM pro GROUP BY category
```

i get only `f` and `c`

How i can query to get all `m,f,c` only once?!

Comment: could you add some more information about that table you use, like the create statement? (I would assume that SELECT DISTINCT category should do exactly what you want)

Comment: your problem is not the sql sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT * FROM pro GROUP BY `category`
```

Comment: @user1612293 How are you using it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07e82/2 returns 'm', 'f', 'c'.

Comment: I think that @alexn answer and mine are corrects. Also SELECT category FROM pro GROUP BY category must return m,f and c. The problem could be in your php code

Comment: Yep. Seems that is broken my PHP code is broken not my SQL command.

Answer (score 3):

```
select category from pro group by category
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a issue in your PHP implementation.

Your query will get all your categories.

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM pro
```

Take a look here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b81e0/2

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    pro a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  category, MIN(details) minDetail
            FROM    pro
            GROUP BY    category
        ) b ON a.category = b.category AND
                a.details = b.minDetail
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b81e0/3)

*follow-up question: what will be the output from the `details` column?*